# iOS coredata: how do you set a breakpoint to the accessor of core data attribute,which is generated by @dynamic

Tags: ios, core-data

Simply use symbolic break point like `-[EntityName setAttribute:]` doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "break" when a value of core data change?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404111/how-to-break-when-a-value-of-core-data-change)

Comment: @ValentinRadu: Core Data generates dynamic accessor methods at runtime, setting a symbolic breakpoint on that is not possible (or at least difficult). As a workaround, you can provide a custom accessor method as shown in the answer to above-mentioned duplicate. A very similar solution is given below.

Comment: I don't know why this was closed a "not a real question", I voted to close it as a "duplicate". If one reads the title then the question becomes quite clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dwayne,

Core Data accessors aren't tricky but they aren't standard either. If you want to catch one, and still have CD operate properly, the accessor needs more support than Mundi lists above. (His answer is correct in design and intent, just not complete.)

```
...
@property (nonatomic) NSString *primitiveStringAttribute;
...
@dynamic stringAttribute, primitiveStringAttribute;
...
- (NSString *) stringAttribute {

  NSString *attribute = nil;

  [self willAccessValueForKey: @"stringAttribute"];

  attribute = self.primitiveStringAttribute;

  [self  didAccessValueForKey: @"stringAttribute"];

  return attribute;
}
```

Andrew

Answer (score -1):

You can still override the @dynamic accessor.

```
...
@dynamic stringAttribute;
...

-(NSString *)stringAttribute {
    return stringAttribute;         // breakpoint here.
}
```

Comment: Core Data attributes are not backed up by instance variables, so I doubt that this works.

Comment: You are right, no underscore, unless you declare the variable yourself (which is also feasible).